# Pull Data from Spreadsheet but only Display the Last Four Digits Using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-masking

I use Apps Script to pull data from Google Spreadsheets and then Display the data on an HTML page in a table format.

I am trying to hide the data that is pulled from the spreadsheet and displayed on the table but make the last four digits of the data to be visible.

I tried the JS code below and it works fine on HTML pages but the JS code doesn't work when I tried to apply it to Apps Script probably because the HTML page has its table value typed as text in the cells while Apps Script needs to pull its table value from the spreadsheet before applying the rule from the JS code to the data to hide it and only display the last four digits of the data.

Any help to understand how to apply the script below to Apps Script to hide data but show the last four digits will be appreciated.

**JS and HTML Code Below;**

```js
var id_number = document.getElementById('data2');
id_number.innerHTML = new Array(id_number.innerHTML.length-3).join('x') + 
id_number.innerHTML.substr(id_number.innerHTML.length-4, 4);
console.log(id_number.innerHTML);

var phone = document.getElementById('data3');
phone.innerHTML = new Array(phone.innerHTML.length-3).join('x') + 
phone.innerHTML.substr(phone.innerHTML.length-4, 4);
console.log(phone.innerHTML);
```

```html
<table>
                  
              <tr>
                    <td width = "120">ID NUMBER</td>
                    <td width = "15">:</td>
                    <td id="data2" class="hidetext">1234567890</td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td>PHONE</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td id="data3" class="hidetext">0000000000</td>
                  </tr>  
                  
</table>
```

**My Code.gs Code in Apps Script Below;**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate()
  .setTitle("HTML DATA PAGE")
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
};

let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function getData(keyword){
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  let data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  let index = data.map(d => d[2]).indexOf(keyword);
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.map(d => d[2]));
  console.log(index);
  if(index > -1){
    return data[index];
  }else{
    return undefined;
  }
  
}

let url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
```

**My Apps Script Table Code in Index.html**

```
 <table>
                  
              <tr>
                    <td width = "120">ID NUMBER</td>
                    <td width = "15">:</td>
                    <td id="data2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>PHONE</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td id="data3"></td>
                  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `keyword` of `getData(keyword)` and your showing HTML. And, in your sample Javascript, it seems that 2 values are required to be used like `ID NUMBER : xxxxxx7890` and `PHONE : xxxxxx0000`. But, in your Google Apps Script, it seems that only one value is returned. So, I cannot understand your expected result. I apologize for this. Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: I think I am causing confusion because I didn't post the complete code for my Apps Script Index.html. please check this link https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx1yb9U1e2_fqbXLkleEO_xSrYSN9OaADNmdGU1J8nlk_WfxXG_QG51tsBlwAZRBe8/exec to see how my project works. Input 12345678 when it asks for a keyword. After that, I can explain further what I am trying to achieve. Thanks :)

Comment: So, instead of `9797979` you want to display `xxxx7979`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do - onit